# In KDE4, how do I open a konsole window that is automatically maximized, stays below all windows, and sticks on all desktops?

Tags: konsole, window-management, kde4

I am using KDE4.
I'd like to create a keyboard shortcut that would run konsole with a predetermined setting:

- window fully maximized
- no menus, no tabs, no windows borders
- stays below all windows
- sticks on all desktops.

All of this can be done by menus and clicks,
but the idea is to run it with a keyboard shortcut,
so I hope there are either konsole options for that,
or some configuration I can store in a konsole profile
that I could specify at the command line.

Comment: You might find some partial answers in the [user scripts](https://store.kde.org/browse?cat=210&ord=latest) of the KDE store.

Comment: @meuh : how (today) can you guess the compatibility of these scripts with kde**4** ?

Comment: @MC68020 It is difficult finding kde4 examples, as the store likes to show the latest uploads. If you sort by rating you see some older items, and then look at the category of one of them to see if there are others of the same vintage, eg [Plasma 4 extensions](https://store.kde.org/browse?cat=106&ord=latest). I'm not a kde user, and I know there were major changes from 4 to 5.

Comment: I should probably look into wmctrl